# storybook angular throw error as 'req' is not defined

Tags: angular, angular8, storybook, angular-storybook

I am trying to integrate the `storybook` by following the steps from [enter link description here](http://www.learnstorybook.com)

but getting the following error:

[image: error thrown]

any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is from your backend,I can imagine that backend is on nodeJs + express, and that error comes when you hit an endpoint and req is not set on the beginning, or the code is encapsulating and they try to use req in a function who doesn't recieve that parameter